# what is the right way to pass a pointer as an argument to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Suppose I am defining a function that prints the elements of a multi-dimensional array.

```
int print(int *a)
{
 for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{ 
for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
{  
cout<< *((a+i*4)+j);}
}
}
return 0;}
```

When I call this function in main using -

```
int c=print(int *a) or print(a)
```

it shows error but gives correct output when called using

```
int c=print((int*)a)
```

What is the difference between these 3?

Comment: I assume that this is C++ - Why not use `std::array`?

Comment: And why does `print` not return a value?

Comment: Suppose you define a function returning `int` and then fail to include a `return` statement in the implementation of that function. What do you think using the return value of a function you've not returned a value from would be? And how would you expect that function to work properly? The most important thing to learn about writing code is how to actually **read** the code you're writing and understand what it does (and does NOT) do.

Comment: I know that it should return an integer but that's not the error I was facing!

Comment: The error you are facing is that you're posting code that  is nonsense and asking us to explain why it isn't working. **Post your real code**, not something you're making up for the purposes of your question, and **ask a specific question about that code**.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

PLEASE READ FIRST:  Methods described here may cause a MEMORY LEAK. You may never cast a pointer without taking considerations about memory alignment and size.

1. this is a bad call.

   ```
   int c=print(int *a);
   ```
2. this should be the right way, you should ensure that "a" is a pointer to a int, case else you may have a memory leak, pay attention to your compiler warnings.

   ```
   int c=print(a);
   ```
3. in this case your're doing a explicit cast of A, forcing it to be a pointer to a int, no matter of what do you really have, you can cause a memory leak, pay attention to your compiler warnings.

   ```
   int c=print((int*)a);
   ```

**Note**

Working with pointers in C/C++ is very dangerous if you are not very clear about this concepts.  if you dont cast your pointers any error in this stage may cause a fatal memory leak. A memory leak is a memory disaligment, caused by situations like this one, it may crash your program or any part of it when pointers are not in the right cast.

About your title:

Your're asking about the difference between "int*" and "(int*)", your question is not well formed. It may be:

**"what is the right way to pass a pointer as an argument to a function"**

Comment: Why is the first one a bad call? It also tells that 'a' is a pointer to int. We use it in defining the arguments of the function and all.

Comment: case1  is a bad call because you are writing a code that should go when you are defining the function. This is a error. You should proceed as case2 or 3.
In the case3,: this is called "cast", it is a explicit convertion from one pointer to another.

Comment: @HunarJain: It's just a syntax error, and makes no sense. The fact that you use it in defining the arguments of the function is irrelevant, that doesn't mean it's OK to use it in a completely different context. `int c = print(Hi, Compiler! This is a pointer to int ----> a);` also "tells that `a` is a pointer to int", but it too is a syntax error.

Comment: @christian: You have (2) and (3) in your answer back to front. If `a` is a pointer to `char`, for instance, then using the cast in (3) is the option that is "very dangerous", because you're forcing the compiler to accept something likely to be nonsensical. (2) will just fail to compile when the types don't match, which is what you want, so that's the best option. Also, "memory leak" means something totally different to what you are describing.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths yes, it is very dangerous to cast a byte to a int. is not the case in this answer. I am trying to explain the right way, not the consecuences of the bad usage of the C language.

Comment: @christian: That may be what you are trying to do. It's not what you are succeeding in doing. Your answer is full of errors, and that's why it got downvoted. "If you dont cast your pointers any error in this stage may cause a fatal memory leak", for instance, is absurd. Not only will it not cause a memory leak, but casting pointers is almost always a symptom of an error, not a solution to one. The correct solution to this question is to change `print()` so that it accepts the right type of pointer.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths  -1 for you man,  please read carefully my answer prior to down vote it.